# preventing process being scheduled

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am creating a kernel module for linux. I was wondering, how can I stop a process from being scheduled for a specified time? Is there a function in the sched.c that can do this? Is it possible to add a specfic task_struct to a wait queue for a certain defined period of time or use something like schedule_timeout for a specific process?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See how linux kernel mutex lock code does this. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/mutex.c#L142

Comment: I'm not sure what part of that function in mutex.c accomplishes this task, I can't see a function that takes a task_struct along with a timeout.

How can I add a task_struct to a wait queue? If I could do that then I could just use a sleep function for the wait queue with a timeout

Comment: Do you want to make the current task sleep?  Or do you want one task to force another task to sleep?

Comment: I think the answer is the same as this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695124/is-it-possible-to-block-a-task-from-kernel-space/9073821#9073821

Answer (score 0):

Delaying process scheduling for a time is equivalent to letting it sleep. In drivers, this is often done with msleep() (common in work tasks), or for processes, by placing the process into interruptable sleep mode with

```
set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTABLE);
schedule_timeout(x*HZ);
```

The kernel will not schedule the task again until the timeout has expired or a signal is received.